# How get existing attribute groups?

Tags: attributes, group

Magento comes with the 'Default' group, but it is possible to create new groups based in attributes of 'Default' group.

I need get the names of the groups existing.

```
Example:

I have 3 groups, 'Default', 'Test', 'Test2' both have the
same tabs and attributes of 'Default'.
```

I want to generate a loop that returns me the three names, 'Default', 'Test', 'Test2' and not your tabs and attributes

I am creating a new attribute in my module, and precisso it to appear in all groups, so far only got on 'Default', because  not  got successful in getting the names of the groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection you are looking for is

```
Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')
```

and with that in mind you can iterate through the collection items and get the info you need as in any other collection.

Comment: Thus returns 'General'

Comment: IT is correct if you have only one group.

Comment: Thus it's like to return only the tabs by group

Comment: Please be clearer since this is the collection you are looking for if you need to see the attribute groups present in Magento.